# What is the purpose of await() in CountDownLatch?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, countdownlatch, cyclicbarrier

I have the following program, where I am using `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` and without using `await()` method it's working fine.

I am new to concurrency and want to know the purpose of `await()`. In `CyclicBarrier` I can understand why `await()` is needed, but why in `CountDownLatch`?

Class `CountDownLatchSimple`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
  Thread one = new Thread(new Runner(latch),"one");
  Thread two = new Thread(new Runner(latch), "two");
  Thread three = new Thread(new Runner(latch), "three");

  // Starting all the threads
  one.start(); two.start(); three.start();
  
}
```

Class `Runner` implements `Runnable`:

```
CountDownLatch latch;

public Runner(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.latch = latch;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is Waiting.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    latch.countDown();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is Completed.");
}
```

#### OUTPUT

> two is Waiting.
> three is Waiting.
> one is Waiting.
> one is Completed.
> two is Completed.
> three is Completed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CountDownLatch` is the synchronization primitive which is used to wait for all threads completing some action.

Each of the thread is supposed to mark the work done by calling `countDown()` method. The one who waits for the action to be completed should call `await()` method. This will wait indefinitely until all threads mark the work as processed, by calling the `countDown()`. The main thread can then continue by processing the worker's results for example.

So in your example it would make sense to call `await()` at the end of `main()` method:

```
latch.await();
```

Note: there are many other use cases of course, they don't need to be threads but whatever that runs usually asynchronously, the same latch can be decremented several times by the same task etc. The above describes just one common use case for `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Thanks Zbynek for the quick reply. So does it mean multiple countdowns from the same thread will be considered as one?

Comment: @hungry : No. Each countdown counts, no matter whether it's from the same thread. It doesn't know anything about thread actually.